# Server -> Desktop Push API

Tags: push, notifications

I am looking for solution which can push automatically a certain event (let's say RSS message) realtime to a desktop user. A toolbar app or a desktop (growl like) will be super for this push.

I have looked at few options but cannot find much info on these kind of apps.

I have looked at conduit - it sucks as there is lot of other fancy options which I am not interested in offering to users.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

G-WAN provides such an API and an [example pushing stocks](http://gwan.com/source/comet.c) in a Web browser (but any client would work).

You can push whatever data format you wish. The API is very simple.

I am part of the project so I can tell that feedback is welcome: feel free to suggest modifications or new features to better match your needs.